# What is tppabs attribute?

Tags: html

As the title suggest, I've encountered this tag today. Searched for it, however couldn't find anything informative. It is something like this

```
<a href="activities.html" tppabs="http://www.dreamguys.co.in/hrms/activities.html">
```

What is the meaning of "tppabs" attribute?

Comment: looks like one that the original coder made up (maybe before the time of data- attributes), perhaps might have used it in some js or something

Comment: That is not a standard attribute. These are sometimes used in JS code to provide some info they need, without affecting the normal behavior of things. You'll have to look at the JS to figure out what they're using it for (you can ctrl-f it, and then share that part of the code)

Comment: Search for `tppabs` in this page: http://www.tenmax.com/teleport/support.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From:
http://www.tenmax.com/teleport/support.htm

> **Q:  I notice that the HTML pages Teleport creates will have "tppabs" tags in them.  What are these and can I remove them?**
>
> A:  The tppabs tags are created and used by Teleport as part of its Link Localization system.  You can prevent the tags from being inserted by turning OFF Link Localization on the Project Properties, Browsing/Mirroring page; but then the links between files may not work correctly in the offline copy.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a default attribute and will more than likely be a custom created attribute, you will need to look at your code to find out more.

Answer (score 1):

Elements (like div and a) have starting and ending tags, and starting tags can contain attributes.

As for the status of tppabs, it has never existed. It's inserted into markup by [Teleport Pro](https://www.webmasterworld.com/forum21/7664.htm) and contains the absolute form of a URL. This allows the software to locate a resource once the document has been downloaded. It serves no purpose as far as HTML is concerned.